# Calculate which VLAN I belong to, based on IP and Mask

Tags: networking, ip

Given an ip address: 175.28.234.18 and mask 255.255.248.0
which VLAN I belong to?

```
   1)  232
   2)  267
   3)  222
```

and why ?

Comment: this doesn't make any sense: you're mixing lan/subnets with vlans. A vlan can be mapped to some specific subnets, but it's not a guarantee you are in that vlan at all.

Comment: Bonus question: Given the above; which WLAN do I belong to?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect 'VLAN' here is a typo, and you meant 'LAN'. In this case, the correct answer is 1.

Explanation: the network mask tells which bits in the address 'belong' to the network address. Since `255.255.248.0` in binary is `11111111 11111111 11111000 00000000`, the network address is `175.28.234.18 & 255.255.248.0 = 175.28.232.0` (`234 & 248 = 232`).